# Angular Errors during JIT compilation when upgrading to Angular 13 with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, jit

I have just been upgrading a project form Angular 12 to Angular 13 and ran into a bunch of JIT errors when running my unit tests.  In particular, I had a lot of errors along the lines of:

- Errors during JIT compilation of template for
  AeroAccordionTabComponent: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an
  unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
- Errors during JIT compilation of template for ErrorComponent: Opening tag "h1" not terminated.
- Unexpected closing tag "h1". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag (yes, this closing tag was the closing tag for the previous one that said it wasn't terminated.
- etc.

However, the templates were fine.  Particularly as they had just been working prior to the upgrade to angular 13.

At one point, I thought it was related to ngClass, as that is the only thing I was using with braces in the particlar template.  But other templates didn't use ngClass, but did use ng-template.

I thought perhaps some of my other libraries were causing issues, so I spent time upgrading them, just in case.

I also thought it might be cache related, so I went through cleaning out all my build/dev caches.

I found one Angular bug report very similar to mine, but the OP was using a custom builder, and the angular representative indicated they didn't support custom builders.  My project happens to use a custom builder as well.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came across a bug report to webpack with the same symptoms.  Turns out, we were using the html-loader to load the template files, such as this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

However, the webpack team said that the html-loader doesn't work with non-standard HTML, which angular obviously uses in templates.  They suggested the use of asset/source instead of html-loader for the templates.  So I updated the above code to this:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
    ],
  },
```

And it solved my problem.  Not sure exactly what changed with webpack and/or html-loader so that it worked with Angular 12, but not Angular 13, but whatever happened, using 'asset/source' worked great.

Posting this in hopes it might save someone else some time.